# How to online resize the root partition? (ext4)

Tags: partitioning, ext4

i've got a 1tb harddisk with 3 partitons:

- fat32 /boot/efi
- ext4 /
- linux-swap

My ext4 partition has 700 GiB free so i would like to use some of that space (like 200 gib) for a Windows 8 partition.

How can i free some space if the partition is in use?

Thanks for all answers

Comment: Does the duplicate help you out?